# Truffle test: could not find local build/contracts

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I have create a truffle project with this command:

```
truffle unbox react
```

I have run this commands:

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts 
npm install @openzeppelin/test-helpers
npm install @openzeppelin/test-environment
```

I have removed all files in tests/ folder. I have kept sample contract SimpleStorage.sol in contracts/ folder.

I have wrote this test and i put it in a file in tests/ folder:

```
const { BN, expectEvent, expectRevert } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
const { accounts, contract } = require('@openzeppelin/test-environment');
const SimpleStorage = contract.fromArtifact('SimpleStorage');

describe('SimpleStorage', function () {
   
}
```

I compile and launch the tests (no error at compile step)

```
truffe compile
truffle test
```

i get this error:

> Error: Could not find local build/contracts when looking for local
> artifacts

Any idea ?

Comment: This happens when the `build` folder is not correctly updated. You can try to clear it and run again 'truffle compile`.

Comment: I have no build folder...

Comment: Then create a folder `build/contracts`.

Comment: It does not change anything, this folder stay empty. Please note i've create this project with "truffle unbox react" command so there might be a place where compiled contracts are stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In truffle to import artifacts use `artifacts.require` like this:

```
const SimpleStorage = artifacts.require('SimpleStorage');
```